# Washing machine cord- only green wire- other wires do not have colors?

Tags: electrical

How can I identify which is black and which is white?

Comment: Is this the cord that came with the washer? Are you trying to replace the cord cap? Where are you on the planet and who is the manufacturer of your machine? Please edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: Some times the neutral is tinned or silver in color where the hot is just copper.

Answer (score 1):

First, are you using a heavy enough line cord? Washing machines are fairly high draw appliances owing to the motor (and water heat if equipped) and should have *at the very least* a 14AWG if not 12AWG cord -- or whatever the previous cord was *if you are positive it was the factory cord*. In my experience, those cords come with 3-color wires, and usually light 16AWG cords don't color.  Just indulge me and check to be sure.

Granted, I have seen thick extension and appliance cords that are flat.  However I am used to the conductors having colored insulation .

If you have a flat cable such as that, with no markings, look for either ribs on the edge of one side, or the cable lettering  or a stripe on one side.   Follow it down to the plug (the tall pin is the neutral) but typically the neutral is the ribbed, striped or lettered side.   Ground is in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to verify you are talking about the washing machine and not the dryer.

Why are the cord's inner wires visible?  You may want a new cord at this point.

Most residential washing machines are 120V in the US. If you see which prong the wires connect to on the plug then the smaller flat prong is the black (hot) wire and the larger flat prong is the white (neutral) wire.

Answer (score -3):

Looking at the plug blades the one that is wider should be your black one but your receptacle could be wired backward best to use a meter. Go to Youtube and resaerch it out

Comment: The wider blade indicates the neutral conductor. That's usually white, right? Also, telling someone to "go look it up" isn't appropriate in an answer.